# RxJava MissingBackpressureException not thrown

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

We are using a lot of RxJava1 code in our Android app. Recently, we started getting a lot of `MissingBackpressureException` thrown around. So I tried understanding the mechanism around backpressure better.

I'm able to get a backpressure exception to be thrown

```
BehaviorSubject<Integer> subject = BehaviorSubject.create();

subject
    .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
    .subscribe(x -> {
        try {
            logger.info("got " + x);
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
});

for (int i = 0; true; ++i) {
    logger.info("sending " + i);
    subject.onNext(i);
}
```

That's great, I get a `MissingBackpressureException`, but when I cause the `subscribe` action to never return, I no longer get `MissingBackpressureException`, so this code:

```
subject
    .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
    .subscribe(x -> {
        while(true) {
            try {
                logger.info("got " + x);
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
});
```

So I got a few questions here:

1. Why am I not getting `MissingBackpressureException` thrown in the 2nd subscriber?
2. What happens to all the objects? I don't see the memory footprint getting larger, so I assume that they are thrown away? why?
3. When I try to do it with `RxJava2` by adding `toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.ERROR)` to the subscriber, I'm not getting an exception in either of the cases, what's happening here?

   ```
       subject
           .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
           .toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.ERROR)
           .subscribe(x -> {
   ```

Comment: You shouldn't get MBE with Subjects and Observables in 2.x. Please post the entire stacktrace of the exception.

Comment: @akarnokd I'm using RxJava1, RxJava2 was just for comparison using a `toFlowable`, which should produce a MBE if I understand correctly. But it does not, and that's my question, why?. There is no stack-trace to attach because I'm not getting an exception and I don't understand why.

Comment: You have an infinite loop in the onNext handler, that prevents the MBE from reaching the default error handler of subscribe.

Comment: @akarnokd Oh I see, thanks!. So what happens to all the objects that are allocated and sent to `onNext`? I don't see the memory exploding... are they just thrown away at some point?